# Missing records in cdc capture instance - MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016, change-data-capture

We have a Source table (MSSQL Server database) and cdc is enabled on it. Most of the time cdc captures all changes that happened in Source table correctly,
but time to time changed records are missing
from cdc shadow table. Did anybody see that strange behavior? Any suggestions how to resolve it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome!  Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server being used.

Comment: we are using SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU8)